# JAXB - Ignore intermediate element

Tags: xml, jaxb, mapping

Can I map a JAXB structure to an XML structure in such a way to ignore an unknown intermediate element?

```
@XmlRootElement(name="foo")
public class Foo {
   @XmlElement(name="bar")
   Bar bar;
}
```

To match XML similar to

```
<foo>
  <unknown>
    <bar/>
  </unknown>
</foo>
```

Comment: I do not think its possible for `JAXB` to ignore the element automatically. You can use `JAXB Moxy` and use the `@XmlPath("unknown/bar")` to avoid creating the additional class or you can maybe try to create `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` and ignore it and obtain just the inner values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accomplished it by

- using javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder to parse the XML String to get the root Node
- wrote breadth first search of the XML tree for the Element with tag name "bar"
- then used javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller to unmarshal that Node into my JAXB object.